# Ubuntu: crypt user's home directory and protect from admin?

Tags: ubuntu

I have the following problem:

I need to run some scripts on a Ubuntu machine but I do not want those scripts to be visible by anybody. What could be the best way to do that ?
I was thinking of the following:

- create a particular user
- Add the scripts in this user's home directory
- Protect + crypt the user's home directory => Can I run the script from outside if the directory is crypted ? Can superuser see the content of the home dir ?

Is there a right way to do this ?

**UPDATE**

I thing the best way would be that root own those scripts. In this case I would need to allow an another user to modify the network configuration. Is it possible to ONLY provide network rights to a user ? (via sudo or else)

Comment: What are you actually wanting to accomplish here?  What's in those scripts that makes you believe that it is important to keep the sysadmin from viewing their contents?

Comment: @dave-sherohman Those scripts contains some admin login/password and the process used to transfer data to some other high sensibility systems.

Answer (score 0):

A correctly implemented encrypted directory (such as the one created by the Ubuntu installer, which uses [ecryptfs](http://ecryptfs.sourceforge.net/)) will **not** be readable unless it's mounted.

Answer (score 0):

The superuser can't see it *while it's encrypted*, but if you create it, (the encrypted dir) or use it, of course root can see it all.

There is no right way to do this, in fact, there *cannot* be *any* way of doing this.

If you're willing to let go of theory, I suppose you could put it all in a virtual private server, or, if you're worried about users other than root, perhaps as little as a an [LXC](http://lxc.sourceforge.net) namespace.